# apply, apply-primitive-procedure and apply-in-underlying-scheme

Tags: scheme, sicp

`Apply` is defined in [4.1.1 The Core of the Evaluator of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.1) as:

```
(define (apply procedure arguments)
  (cond ((primitive-procedure? procedure)
         (apply-primitive-procedure ;
          procedure
          arguments));

        ((compound-procedure? procedure)
        .....
        (else
        ....)
```

I referenced the definition of `apply-primitive-procedure` in "4.1.4 Rnning the Evaluator as a Program" as:

```
(define (apply-primitive-procedure proc args)
  (apply-in-underlying-scheme
   (primitive-implementation proc) args))
```

So `apply-primitive-procedure` is implemented by `apply-in-underlying-scheme`

Nonetheless, refer to the footnotes:

> `Apply-in-underlying-scheme` is the `apply` procedure we have used in earlier chapters. The metacircular evaluator's `apply` procedure
>   ([[4.1.1]]) models the working of this primitive. Having two different
>   things called `apply` leads to a technical problem in running the
>   metacircular evaluator, because defining the metacircular evaluator's
>   `apply` will mask the definition of the primitive. One way around this is to rename the metacircular =apply= to avoid conflict with the name
>   of the primitive procedure. We have assumed instead that we have saved
>   a reference to the underlying =apply= by doing
>   `(define apply-in-underlying-scheme apply)`
>   before defining the metacircular `apply`. This allows us to access the original version of `apply` under a different name.

It states the `apply-in-underlying-scheme` is `apply` in 4.1.1.

In  a summary:

```
 ,-> apply -> apply-primitive-procedure -> apply-in-underlying-scheme --.
 '----------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

I guess it not a recursion.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: I think "[w]e have assumed instead that we have saved a reference to the underlying `apply` [...] before defining the metacircular `apply`" is pretty clear.

Comment: got it finally, `apply` was not mystified as `eval` but as `cons` and `list` which take it for granted to use. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Apply` means function application for everything that is not a special form (the special forms are considered in `eval`).  `Apply` is a recursive function that will *ever* finish.

`Apply` is subdivided in 2 cases of procedure application:

-- *internal* to the system that implements the language

This is the place where is made the transition between the target language and the language that is used to implement the target language (source language).

Here you need to evaluate each parameter (through `eval`) and convert the resulting object to a similar object in source language before to call the application function of the source language.  For some parameters the recursion of `eval->apply` may happen.

-- a *combination* created in the target language by using the means of combination that the target language provides.

In this case also you need to recursively call `eval` for each parameter and use function application in the target language.  In this case you do not need to convert the result of `eval` to an object in the source language.

So in case of combinations there is also recursion in `apply`, but it is a kind of recursion that will finish (function application function is a [*primitive-recursive function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function)) because you evaluate a smaller piece each time (operator, operands vs the full initial expression).

I think that you did not notice that `apply` is a primitive-recursive operator and you were afraid it will not finish.

Comment: I am not sure is that `(define apply-in-underlying-scheme apply)`, the apply is scheme's builtin `apply` or the apply which was defined in `(define (apply procedure arguments)`?

Comment: Oh, I got the idea, we did not define a primitive apply as an eval instead we use a primitive apply just as cons and list.